# при клике мышкой на любом месте сайта изменение страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-дизайн

Здраствуйте, хочу понять как выполняется переход на другую страницу сайта при клике на на этом сайте https://weareundefined.be/

понял что используется эта библиотека https://revealjs.com/

возможно кто-то что-то подскажет

Answer (score 0):

Судя по network браузера - никакие переходы на другие страницы не осуществляются.
Просто при клике мышкой запускается функция, которая меняет классы, стили, innerHTML некоторых элементов на станице и делает кое-что ещё.
Интерактив (с игрой в пинг-понг, рисованием) реализован с использованием canvas.
Резюмируя - в плане технической реализации, никаких "чудес" нет, всё довольно просто и прозрачно. В плане творческой задумки - не мне судить.

Comment: @c-k-rim спасибо за ответ, если вам не трудно можете немного подробнее рассказать как это можно сделать.
Я вижу что эта библиотека https://revealjs.com/ работает как слайдер, но перелистывает страницу при нажатии на кнопки, можно было бы как-то дописать к ней код, чтобы страница листал при клике на любом месте
p.s я только начал изучать js